# use getters in toString generation

Tags: intellij-idea, code-generation, tostring

I would like to use getters in `toString` code generation in Intellij. In IDE settings I choosen option `Enable getters in code generation ($methods)`, but it does not do the job. How to configure Intellij to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IntelliJ does not offer you to use the getters if it can directly access the field. But it will list your getters if they are renamed:

```
String myField;

public String getMyField() { return myField; } // will not be listed in toString generation

public String pleaseGetMyField() { return myField; } // will be listed in toString generation
```